# What's in the middle of the arithmetic and geometric mean?

Tags: calculus

Arithmetic mean of two positive reals is $A(x,y) = \frac{(x+y)}{2}$.  Geometric mean of two positive reals is $G(x,y) = \sqrt{(x*y)}$. Is there an easy way to compute the limit of the iteration $(x,y) \Leftarrow ( A(x,y),G(x,y) )$, i.e. the "mean" that is not arithmetic nor geometric, but something in between?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the arithmetic–geometric mean, and is discussed at this wiki page.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean
There are other means:
$$((a^p+b^p)/2)^{1/p}$$
for any value of $p$.  For example, $p=1$ is the arithmetic mean, $p=2$ gives the 'root-mean-square', $p=-1$ gives the 'harmonic mean', and you get the geometric mean by letting $p$ approach $0$.

Comment: $(+1)$ for the amazing insight expressed in the last paragraph. :-$)$